# What is the meaning of '%' + '" + data + "' + '%'?

Tags: c#, sql

Here is the code,.

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[LDDAP-ADA_Header] WHERE ADANo LIKE '%' + '" + data + "' + '%'";
```

Comment: It is used to find match at any location in the string of database column, it checks if column contains the provided string.

Comment: You can visit the w3school site. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: Yeah but I am confused at this code + '" + data + "' +,.

Comment: @James Do you understand that text inside `"` is a string, and that `+` will concatenate strings? Try using the debugger and evaluate `query` after this statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a combination of C# string concatenation and SQL string concatenation.

C# part:

```
string b = "B";
string x = "A" + b + "C";
//gives you  "ABC"
```

SQL:

```
'A' + 'B' + 'C'
// gives you 'ABC'
```

Combined:

```
sql = "'A' + '" + b + "' + 'C'";
```

Results in C# string

```
sql = "'A' + 'B' + 'C'"
```

Which results in SQL in

```
'ABC'
```

In your case, it results in

```
ADANo LIKE '%mydata%'
```

while mydata is the contents of `data`. It uses the `LIKE` comparsion operator on the field `ADANo`, which returns all the records where `data` is contained in `ADANo`. The `%` characters are wildcards, which mean that any number of any character can be before or after `data`.

---

By the way, if `data` is coming from the user, this kind of code is vulnerable to SQL injection. It means, that a user can execute arbitrary SQL on the database by passing it as `data` with some tricks. To avoid this, use a parameterized query.

Comment: This answer is more clear to me,.Thank you so much for the help Sir! :) :) :),.Can you give a an example of parameterized query Sir??

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer ... :-) It depends on the data access layer you have. Often you do not use ADO.NET directly. Probably this helps here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

That is how the Like operator works.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name LIKE pattern
```

The "%" sign is used to define wildcards (missing letters)

WHERE title LIKE '%computer%' finds all strings with the word 'computer' anywhere in the string.

Comment: But, how about this one? + '" + data + "' +? Why there are "+" symbols??What do they mean in the code??

Comment: That is a concatenation of whole string. `data`'s runtime value is replaced.

Comment: it is way fo doing string concatenation......I think you need to go through some C#  and SQL tutorials..this is very basic stuff

Comment: @James : welcome if this helped you - consider [selecting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

It indeed looks redundant to split the `'%' and 'data'.

If we use the new `$` syntax we get this:

`var query = $"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[LDDAP-ADA_Header] WHERE ADANo LIKE '%' + '{data}' + '%'";`

Now suppose `data` is `foobar`.

This results in

`var query = $"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[LDDAP-ADA_Header] WHERE ADANo LIKE '%' + 'foobar' + '%'";`

Which in turn results in

`SELECT * FROM [dbo].[LDDAP-ADA_Header] WHERE ADANo LIKE '%foobar%'`

So you can rewrite your statement to:

`var query = $"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[LDDAP-ADA_Header] WHERE ADANo LIKE '%{data}%'";`

Or with your string concat syntax:

`var query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[LDDAP-ADA_Header] WHERE ADANo LIKE '%" + data + "%'";`

Do notice that this approach (in general, not before or after these changes) is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

For example, what's the query when `data` is `"FOO'; DELETE FROM [dbo].[LDDAP-ADA_Header]; --"`

So your end result then is

`"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[LDDAP-ADA_Header] WHERE ADANo LIKE '%FOO'; DELETE FROM [dbo].[LDDAP-ADA_Header]; --%'"`

Which will clear out your table.

Comment: Thanks Sir..What should I put in order to refrain for some SQL Injections??

Comment: @James If you want to write your queries yourself I suggest looking at parameterized queries: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

That's a plain-text search with the `LIKE` operator. 
LIKE uses escape sequences like % to signify "any number of any characters/numbers here".
 
Basically the SQL-equivalent of a regex-search/comparison.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.[LDDAP-ADA_Header] 
WHERE ADANo LIKE '%' + 'foo' + '%'";
```

However, this code contains two mistakes:
1. Not using parameters, so it's vulnerable to SQL-injection. 
2. Not escaping characters inside the string, like `%`

More correctly, this would be:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[LDDAP-ADA_Header] WHERE ADANo LIKE '%' + '" + data.Replace("'", "''") + "' + '%'";
```

assuming data cannot be NULL, which probably doesn't have to be that way.

But for this to actually work, you'd need to use ESCAPE in the like-clause (and concat all characters in the string with `\`).

e.g. `"% of size"` ==> `"\%\ \o\f\ \s\i\z\e"`

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[LDDAP-ADA_Header] 
WHERE ADANo LIKE '%' + @data + '%' ESCAPE '\'
```

The problem is, "data" is most-likely a user input field. 
The (possibly malicious) user can put into that textbox whatever he wants. 
And if you don't do data.Replace("'", "''"), he/she/it can set "data" to

```
string data = "'; DROP DATABASE whatever; -- "
```

and then you will have a problem (e.g. if I put "master" in place of "whatever")

**Warning**
Don't put that string into your data variable, unless you want to miss your master database.

Comment: Thank you Sir for that answer,.:D