# How to pass in sql "like" condition from c# with single quotes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have string variable in c#

```
String Condition = " And LoginName like ''%"+txtLoginName.text+"%''";
```

I pass this condition variable to a stored procedure like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "GetAllUserMasterBySearch";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Condition ", Condition );
```

And my stored procedure is here:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllUserMasterBySearch] (  
    @Condition nvarchar(max)  
    ) 
as
    declare @Query  nvarchar(max) 

    set @Query = 'SELECT
                      [UserMasterId], [LoginName], [UserName],
                      [UserType], [MobileNo], [Email],
                      [IsLogin], [IpAddress]
                  FROM  
                      UserMaster      
                  WHERE 
                      IsActive = 1 ' + @Condition

    print @query   

    EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

How to pass "like" condition from C# ?

Comment: Please read the help on formatting your questions. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, your question in its current form is very hard to follow.

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: @DanBracuk invalid column that I have enter in txtLoginName.Text

Comment: be very careful with building SQL like this. It is vulnerable to SQL injection. In means that the user can execute arbitrary SQL in your database just by using a simple trick and entering it to txtLoginName.text. Use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35193635/what-is-the-meaning-of-data/35194648#35194648

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass only variable and rewrite your SP as following

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllUserMasterBySearch] (  
    @var nvarchar(max)  
) as

declare @Query  nvarchar(max) 
set @Query = 'SELECT
                  [UserMasterId]
                 ,[LoginName]
                 ,[UserName]
                 ,[UserType]
                 ,[MobileNo]
                 ,[Email]
                 ,[IsLogin]
                 ,[IpAddress]
              FROM  
                  UserMaster      
              WHERE 
                  IsActive=1 AND LoginName LIKE %' + @var + '%';

print @query   
EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

Update: If you want to play with dynamic SQL then try ''' instead of ''. Honestly I haven't deal with dynamic SQL for a while since it it terrible and not secure approach (as it was already mentioned in comments)

Comment: @BhavinChhatrola, revised

Comment: @BhavinChhatrola, if you have many columns you shall pass all values as  variables and rewrite your SP accordingly with use of WHERE and CASE. This can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206484/sql-switch-case-in-where-clause